# When starting tomcat I am getting - Failed to instantiate SLF4J LoggerFactory in the logs

Tags: java, tomcat, log4j

INFO [main] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Failed to instantiate SLF4J LoggerFactory
Reported exception:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/Level

Answer (score -1):

You also need the log4j library along with the SLF4J.

Comment: both log4j and slf4j library are there